# Soap 2.5.1 jar upgrade to Java.xml.soap-api

Tags: java, security, soap

I am trying to fix the security flaws of Vera code , while doing identified that soap 2.5.1 jar is not compatible so want to upgrade it to javax.xml.soap-api jar .Can someone help me to find the equivalent method corresponding to below code
Message  message = new Message();
SOAPTransport soaptransport =message.getSOAPTransport();

Trying to identify the equivalent method in javax.xml.soap-api

Comment: What is soap 2.5.1.jar supposed to be? Identify the framework from where that jar file comes from then edit your question to provide more details. Read the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).